# Changing order of DE in python (scipy.integrate.odeint)

Tags: python, differential-equations

I am facing a problem with differential equation (python):

This is my DE:

`m*x"(t) + d*x'(t) + k*x(t) = y(t)`

Where `y(t) = Y * sin(w*t)`

Data:

```
m=3
d=79
k=200000
w=152 
Y=0.05
t=np.linspace(t_0,t_1, n) # not that important.
```

I have to get `numpy.array` of `x(t)` using `scipy.integrate.odeint` and i am having really big issues transforming my DE of 2. order to DE of 1. order.

What i am looking for is func in scipy.integrate.odeint 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html 
based on my equations. And primarily and need to find np.array of x(t), then x'(t) and x''(t).

Answer (score 0):

The usual procedure is to set `v=x'` so that then

```
x' = v
v' = ( y(t) - d*v - k*x) / m
```

or

```
def derivs(u,t):
    x,v = u
    return [ v, ( y(t) - d*v - k*x) / m ]


def y(t): return Y*np.sin(w*t)

t_0, t_1, n = 0, 1, 501
t=np.linspace(t_0,t_1, n)

x0, v0 = 0.0, 0.0
u0 = [ x0, v0 ]

u = odeint(derivs, u0, t)

plt.subplot(2,1,1); plt.title("x(t)"); plt.plot(t, u[:,0])
plt.subplot(2,1,2); plt.title("x'(t)"); plt.plot(t, u[:,1])
plt.show()
```

with the result

[image]

Comment: But won't i get speed (x is movement, x' is speed and x'' is acceleration) from this?

Comment: And i need to get x(t) - movement

Comment: You need to solve the coupled system and then extract your values from the vector-valued result of the numerical integration.

Comment: So if i insert u[:,0] i wil get x(t) ? Because if i do that, the answer is wrong (my data for t=np.linspace(2.5, 4.5, 1900).                                                
And what does this line do: x,v = u

Comment: `x,v = u` unpacks the list/array/vector `u` into its components. The sampling range is less important than the initial conditions, you did not give them.

Comment: I could really use a good explanation with solution in steps as i as a beginner in programming face a lot of difficulties during my work for school.        
Data you need for initial conditions: t_0 = 2.5, t_1=4.5 Initial conditions are: x(t_0)=0, x' (t_0) = 0                                                                                       What is then the solution (x(t)) ?

Comment: This is a wide area, and it is not clear where your understanding is wrt. differential equations and the use of python. You can use the search function to find related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+differential-equations+odeint+order

Comment: Can you just please solve this specific problem? So what is x(t) then ? With what code do i get it? I promise  i will give it more time next time but i am a bit in a hurry with this problem (holidays are coming :) )

Comment: You had that right already, `x=u[:,0]`. You get different solutions for different values of `x0,v0`, you need to give them to specify an initial-value-problem that then has a unique solution.

Comment: What do you mean with : ''you need to give them to specify an initial-value-problem?(my english is not the best, sorry) How can i define the condition in point t_0 ? Or is it this point t_0 defined as 0 (first value) in interval [t_0,t_1] ? (if it is so, why do i get a wrong solution?)

Comment: How did you determine that it is the wrong solution, what do you compare it to? And yes, `x0 = x(t_0)` and `v0 = x'(t_0)`, without these numbers the problem description is incomplete.

Comment: I know it is wrong as this is part of my homework and the solution is not correct.

Comment: Then you did not reproduce the full and complete task description. I do not have it, so I can only chose some convenient demonstrative initial values.

Comment: I think that i know where the problem is (you have my entire data). I can't specify my initial conditions : if i write  x=x(t_0) i get an error x is not defined. And i can't write x' in python, it doesn't mean anything. I marked x as x0 and v as x1, by the way